# Remote domain load browser restriction

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

You know the browser restrictions which disallow remote domain load, ie making this not work:

```
$("#verizon").load("http://verizon.domain.net/?var=rscms&tan=0.9");
```

Is there any way around that? I'd rather not have to iframe the content

Answer (score 1):

You can use a local script written in C#, PHP, or whatever you have access to that can read the contents and relay them back to the jQuery request.

```
$.post("remote-fetch.php", {url:"http://verizon.com"}, function(results) {
  alert(results);
});
```

That would call a local php script that would resemble the following:

```
print file_get_contents($_POST["url"]);
// whatever is printed here will be alerted in our jQuery code
```

Of course you would want to have some more logic within your server-side script than this. My example is merely just a concept of how you could acheive the results you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Some sites have [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) APIs. If the site doesn't have an API for cross-domain requests, I think the best you can do is proxy the content through your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple proxy in PHP or other language that takes the URL as a parameter does curl or the like to return the data to your JavaScript. Just host the proxy on the same domain.